# jQuery Textillate.js - how to "reset" element html and re-start animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am animating text using Textillate.js (http://jschr.github.io/textillate/) on html in a span.

The animations are manually triggered by button click ('in').
After/during the animation, a user can click a "reset" button to re-set the span back to the starting html (which is hidden).
Then the animation should run again manually on "in" button click, but I cannot get it to work.

To make it easy to see what I am trying to do, I created this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nlapolla/mGgd5/225/

Here is the Fiddle code:

```js
$('#tlt').textillate({ 
    autoStart: false,
    loop: true,
    in : { effect: 'bounceInRight' }
});

$('.in').on('click', function () {
    $('#tlt').textillate('in'); 
});

$('.out').on('click', function () {
    $('#tlt').textillate('out'); 
});

$('.reset').on('click', function () {
    $('#tlt').html('Some text');
});
```

```css
#tlt {
    font-size:30px;
}
.hideme {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://jschr.github.io/textillate/assets/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jschr.github.io/textillate/assets/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<script src="http://jschr.github.io/textillate/jquery.textillate.js"></script>

<span id="tlt" class='hideme'>Some text</span>
<br/>
<button class="in">in</button>
<button class="reset">Reset/Hide</button>
```

Any ideas would really be appreciated!  I've been trying to get this to work for hours - searched SO and found a lot of great advice, but nothing helped in this case... thank you for any help you can provide.  :o)

Comment: Someone already made a working fiddle over here: http://jsfiddle.net/jschr/mGgd5/

Comment: Thanks -- but actually that is the Fiddle I started working with - I used it as the basis for my Fiddle.  The problem is that (aside from needing to be initially hidden until the button is clicked) I need it to "reset" and be instantly hidden - and remain hidden until the "in" button is clicked again.  The original Fiddle, starts it over, but it does not hide UNTIL manually triggered to reveal and animate again.  I hope I am making sense.  :o)

Comment: Got you!  I'll create a fiddle and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a re-init event of textillate but what you could to is, delete and recreate the element on reset. And wrap the options in a function and call it on 'in' click. It will work but I'm not a JS expert so pretty sure there are much better ways of doing this.

```
function animate(el) {
  $(el).textillate({
    autoStart: false,
    loop: true,
    in : {
      effect: 'bounceInRight'
    }
  });
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadikyalcin/sL88a2q5/1/)

Comment: Instead of "resetting, I ended up using the manual call to textillate "out" set at a delay of zero seconds.  Then I could manually call the textillate "in".  However, your solution also works and I will probably use it in another project.  Thank you!

Comment: @Nick you are welcome. I'm sure you can find better solutions after some time :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite old, but I built a common function called `retextillate` that you can use to call or re-call textillate on an element and:

- perform your initial call
- re-initialize a given effect on the same element
- change whether you call the `in` animation, the `out` animation, or both.

This should cover everything:

```
function retextillate(element, in_effect = "", out_effect = "", type) {

    /* 
        element : html element with . or # symbol
        effect  : textillate/animate.css effect you're calling
        type    : either in, out, or both
    */

    $(element).textillate({
        loop: true,
        autoStart: false,           
        in : { 
            effect  : in_effect, 
            delay   : 40 
        },
        out : { 
            effect  : out_effect, 
            reverse : true,
            delay   : 40,
            callback : function() {             
                $(element).css('opacity', 0);
            }
        }
    }); 

    if ( type == 'in' ) {

        $(element).textillate('in');
        $(element).css('opacity', 1);

    } else if ( type == 'out' ) {

        $(element).textillate('out');       

    } else if ( type == 'both' ) {

        $(element).textillate('in');
        setTimeout( function() { 
            $(element).textillate('out');
        }, 1000);

    }

}
```

If you're initializing it for the first time, it will go ahead and call textillate on the element.  In order to properly utilize this, you need to define both an `in` effect and an `out` effect, whether you plan on using it or not.  If you don't define one, it will just default to blank, which is okay.

So instead of running this on each element:

```
$('.my_element').textillate({
  in: { effect : 'slideInLeft' }
});
```

Just call it like this:

```
retextillate('.my_element', 'slideinleft', 'fadeOut', 'in');
```

You can play around on the same element over and over without having to refresh the page:

```
retextillate('.my_element', 'slideInLeft', 'fadeOut', 'in'); /* will show the slideInLeft animation, then stop */
retextillate('.my_element', 'tada', '', 'in'); /* will show the tada animation, then stop */
retextillate('.my_element', 'tada', 'fadeOut', 'both'); /* will show the tada animation, then the fadout animation, then stop */
retextillate('.my_element', '', 'fadeOut', 'out'); /* will show the fadeout animation, then stop */
```